# Add colon after algorithm caption/number in IEEE transactions

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran

I am using Overleaf to write an article in IEEE transactions template. I wish to write the caption of Algorithm as, Algorithm 4: (as shown in the picture below). But when I use my code, it shows Algorithm 4 (without full colon). The code I am using for caption is,

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

\caption{Deployment Strategy}

  \begin{algorithmic} [1]

 \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}

 \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

 \REQUIRE AP1=(x,y)\\   

 Total APs= $T_{AP}$

 \ENSURE  All candidate positions C\{1:End\}


 \end{algorithmic} 

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: required]

Comment: Hi Sohaib! Could you add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the problem to your question? The solution might depend on other things in your preamble, that we can't see right now. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see complete compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added the MWE. I hope it has enough details for this specific problem.

Comment: @PaulGessler thanks for your reply. I hope you can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can update `\fnum@algorithm` which is used to set the label and number of the `algorithm` `\caption`. I've just added `:` to the original definition.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@algorithm}{\fname@algorithm{} \thealgorithm:}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Deployment Strategy}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{}l@{} }
      $AP1 = (x,y)$ \\
      Total $APs = T_{AP}$
    \end{tabular}
    \ENSURE All candidate positions $C\{1:\mbox{End}\}$
  \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @SohaibBinAltaf: If this solved your problem, consider [accepting it as such](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764).

Comment: Wonderful suggestion...